# Store time from timepickerdialog

Tags: android

How can I store the time from timepickerdialog in android as separate integers??
If the user enters the time as 20:00 I want to store it as separate integers 22 and 00 for further use.
I have tried many methods..i.e first splitting the string using the split function for ":" and then using parseInt method for both the substrings..But it is not working. Please give a valid solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I customized my `TimePicker` to get the values separate, also Calculated `AM` and `PM` values based on it.

```
public void clicker (View view)
{
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
    mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(AddAlarm.this,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker,
                                      int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    //calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedHour);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);

                    int c_hour,c_min;
                    String format;
                    c_hour=selectedHour;
                    c_min=selectedMinute;

                    if (c_hour == 0) {
                        c_hour += 12;
                        format = "AM";
                    } else if (c_hour == 12) {
                        format = "PM";
                    } else if (c_hour > 12) {
                        c_hour -= 12;
                        format = "PM";
                    } else {
                        format = "AM";
                    }

                    String formatTime = String.format("%02d : %02d %s", c_hour, c_min, format);

                    TextView dimple = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeText);
                    dimple.setText(formatTime);
                    setAlarm(calendar);

                }
            }, hour, minute, false);// Yes 24 hour time
    mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
    mTimePicker.show();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, false);
        }

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            // get hour and minute from here
        }
    }
```

call this timepicker dialog by

```
new TimePickerFragment().show(getFragmentManager(), "starttime");
```

Comment: So you want to show another timepicker dialog in you service class with the values selected by the user

Comment: Basically now I have the time in the string format i.e 20:00 in a service class(passed it using intents). All I want now is to set this time for calendar,HOUR_OF_DAY and Calendar.MINUTE which take integer inputs. So I need to convert 20:00 string to 2 integers 20 and 00.kindly help me doing that.

Comment: public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            // get hour and minute from here
        }

get the hour and minute from above and pass them to service class and set them to calendar